# C - change the last element of the matrix

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

i have array unknown size i want to transfer to matrix[n][2].Example;

```
D[c]=1,2,3,4,5

D[c/2][2]=  1   2
            3   4
            5   0
```

so if size of array odd i want add 0 last member of matrix.Here s my code but i dont know how to make 0 last member of matrix

```
if (c%2==1){c=c+1;}
     for(r=0; r<(c/2); r++)
    {
        for(t=0; t<2; t++)
        {
           v++;
            matris[r][t]=D[v-1];
        }
    }
    matris[r][t]
      printf("\nmatrice:\n\n");
    for(r=0; r<(c/2); r++)
    {
        for(t=0; t<2; t++)
        {
            printf("%3u ", matris[r][t]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to initialise the array to be all zeros:

```
int matris[4][4] = { 0 };
```

Any not set during population would remain zero.